# About the Task.StartNew(Action<Object>, Object) method

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I'm learning the TPL on this page, and one code block confuses me a lot.

I was reading this page: [Task Parallelism (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

in one section, it said that the following code is the right solution because a lambda in a loop can't get the value as it mutates after each iteration, but the final value. So you should wrap the "i" in a CustomData object. The code is below:

```
class CustomData
{
   public long CreationTime;
   public int Name; 
   public int ThreadNum;
}

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      // Create the task object by using an Action(Of Object) to pass in custom data 
      // to the Task constructor. This is useful when you need to capture outer variables 
      // from within a loop. 
      Task[] taskArray = new Task[10];
      for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
      {
         taskArray[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew( (Object obj ) =>
            {
               CustomData data = obj as CustomData;
               if (data == null) 
                  return;

               data.ThreadNum = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
               Console.WriteLine("Task #{0} created at {1} on thread #{2}.", data.Name, data.CreationTime, data.ThreadNum);
            },
            new CustomData()
            {
               Name = i,
               CreationTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks
            });
      }
      Task.WaitAll(taskArray);     
   }
}
```

The code is rather straightforward and easy to understand but here comes my problem:

in the Task.Factory.StartNew() method, the author uses one of its overload form:

```
Task.StartNew(Action<Object>, Object)
```

I am so curious to know **where does the "obj" come from? How does it have 3 properties**: Name, CreationTime and ThreadNum.

I searched over MSDN found no useful detail but this: "An object containing data to be used by the action delegate." [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) It really doesn't explain anything.

Could anyone explain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a more concise example which may help to explain it.

```
void StartNew(Action<object> action, object o) {
  action(o);
}
```

The `StartNew` method just takes the `action` delegate and invokes it by passing `o` as the parameter.  The value passed to the lambda is simply the value that is passed into `StartNew` after the lambda

```
// Prints "hello world"
StartNew(o => Console.WriteLine(o), "hello world");
```

In the case you outlined the value being passed as the second parameter is

```
new CustomData() {Name = i, CreationTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks}
```

This just creates a new object of type `CustomData`, assigns it some properties and makes it the argument to the lambda defined immediately before it.  It will eventually become the value `obj` in the lambda

Comment: One example to rule them all! It explains everything. thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard pattern to pass an opaque state object to a callback, it is used in many other places in .NET framework. A more simple example, [`SendOrPostCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.sendorpostcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(state => 
    MessageBox.Show(state.ToString()), state: "Hello");
```

The callback lambda of type `SendOrPostCallback` will be invoked in the future with "Hello" as `state`.

The `state` parameter can be used as optimization, but it is not really necessary, neither here nor for `Task.Factory.StartNew` or in most other cases a `state` argument is provided.

Your lambda is a *closure* which has access to the outer scope local variables, so the following produces the identical result, without passing the `state` explicitly:

```
var message = "Hello";
SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(_ => 
    MessageBox.Show(message), state: null);
```

The same applies to `Task.Factory.StartNew`. For this purpose, `Task.Factory.StartNew` provides a set of overrides which [accept non-generic action `Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), rather than `Action<object>`.

So, your code might look like this, which is IMO much more readable:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++) {
     var data = new CustomData() {Name = i, CreationTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks};

     taskArray[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
     {
         if (data == null) 
           return;

         data.ThreadNum = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
         Console.WriteLine("Task #{0} created at {1} on thread #{2}.",
             data.Name, data.CreationTime, data.ThreadNum);
     });
  }
```