# Task.Run with Parameter(s)?

Tags: c#, lambda, task-parallel-library, task

I have implemented a simple `Task.Factory.StartNew()` and I wonder how can I do it with `Task.Run()` instead?

Here is the basic code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action<object>(
(x) =>
{
    // Do something with 'x'
}), rawData);
```

I looked into `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` in *Object Browser* and I couldn't find a `Action<T>` like parameter. There is only `Action` that takes `void` parameter and no *type*.

There are only 2 things similiar: `static Task Run(Action action)` and `static Task Run(Func<Task> function)` but can't post parameter(s) with both.

Yes, I know I can create a simple extension method for it but **my main question is can we write it on single line** with `Task.Run()`?

Comment: It's not clear what you'd want the *value* of the parameter to be. Where would it come from? If you've already got it, just capture it in the lambda expression...

Comment: @JonSkeet `rawData` is a network data packet that has a container class (like DataPacket) and I'm re-using this instance to reduce GC pressure. So, if I use `rawData` directly in `Task`, it can (probably) be changed before `Task` handles it. Now, I think I can create another `byte[]` instance for it. I think it's the simplest solution for me.

Comment: Yes, if you need to clone the byte array, you clone the byte array. Having an `Action<byte[]>` doesn't change that.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59799778/5935112) are some **good solutions** to pass parameters to a task.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

```
private void RunAsync()
{
    //Beware of closures.  String is immutable.
    string param = "Hi";
    Task.Run(() => MethodWithParameter(param));
}

private void MethodWithParameter(string param)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

**Edit**

Due to popular demand I must note that the `Task` launched will run in parallel with the calling thread.  Assuming the default `TaskScheduler` this will use the .NET `ThreadPool`.  Anyways, this means you need to account for whatever parameter(s) being passed to the `Task` as potentially being accessed by multiple threads at once, making them shared state.  This includes accessing them on the calling thread.

In my above code that case is made entirely moot.  Strings are immutable.  That's why I used them as an example.  But say you're not using a `String`...

One solution is to use `async` and `await`.  This, by default, will capture the `SynchronizationContext` of the calling thread and will create a continuation for the rest of the method after the call to `await` and attach it to the created `Task`.  If this method is running on the WinForms GUI thread it will be of type `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`.

The continuation will run after being posted back to the captured `SynchronizationContext` - again only by default.  So you'll be back on the thread you started with after the `await` call.  You can change this in a variety of ways, notably using [`ConfigureAwait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait(v=vs.110).aspx).  In short, the rest of that method will not continue until **after** the `Task` has completed on another thread.  But the calling thread will continue to run in parallel, just not the rest of the method.

This waiting to complete running the rest of the method may or may not be desirable.  If nothing in that method later accesses the parameters passed to the `Task` you may not want to use `await` at all.

Or maybe you use those parameters much later on in the method.  No reason to `await` immediately as you could continue safely doing work.  Remember, you can store the `Task` returned in a variable and `await` on it later - even in the same method.  For instance, once you need to access the passed parameters safely after doing a bunch some other work.  Again, you do *not* need to `await` on the `Task` right when you run it.

Anyways, a simple way to make this thread-safe with respect to the parameters passed to `Task.Run` is to do this:

You must first decorate `RunAsync` with `async`:

```
private async void RunAsync()
```

**Important Notes**

Preferably the method marked [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) **should not** return void, as the linked documentation mentions.  The common exception to this is event handlers such as button clicks and such.  They must return void.  Otherwise I always try to return a `Task` or `Task<TResult>` when using `async`.  It's good practice for a quite a few reasons.

Now you can `await` running the `Task` like below.  You cannot use `await` without `async`.

```
await Task.Run(() => MethodWithParameter(param));
//Code here and below in the same method will not run until AFTER the above task has completed in one fashion or another
```

So, in general, if you `await` the task you can avoid treating passed in parameters as a potentially shared resource with all the pitfalls of modifying something from multiple threads at once.  Also, beware of [closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx).  I won't cover those in depth but the linked article does a great job of it.

Regarding `Run` and `StartNew` the code below I find most important to know, really.  There are legitimate reasons to use either, neither is obsolete or "better" than the other.  Be aware simply replacing one with the other is a very bad idea unless you understand this:

```
//These are exactly the same
Task.Run(x); 
Task.Factory.StartNew(x, CancellationToken.None,
TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);

//These are also exactly the same
Task.Factory.StartNew(x);
Task.Factory.StartNew(x, CancellationToken.None, 
TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Current);
```

**Side Notes**

A bit off topic, but be careful using any type of "blocking" on the WinForms GUI thread due to it being marked with `[STAThread]`.  Using `await` won't block at all, but I do sometimes see it used in conjunction with some sort of blocking.

"Block" is in quotes because you technically [cannot block the WinForms GUI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154429/apartmentstate-for-dummies/4156000#4156000).  Yes, if you use `lock` on the WinForms GUI thread it *will* still pump messages, despite you thinking it's "blocked".  It's not.

This can cause bizarre issues in very rare cases.  One of the reasons you never want to use a `lock` when painting, for example.  But that's a fringe and complex case; however I've seen it cause crazy issues.  So I noted it for completeness sake.

Comment: You are not awaiting `Task.Run(() => MethodWithParameter(param));`. Which means that if `param` gets modified **after** the `Task.Run`, you might have unexpected results on the `MethodWithParameter`.

Comment: @Kilouco Of course.  That's the expected behavior when passing by reference.  Same would happen if you did `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => { MethodWithParameter((string)x); }, param);`  Welcome to threading, don't shoot yourself in the foot...

Comment: I'm just suggesting giving OP a heads-up about this risk.

Comment: I'm accepting answer because of clear/simple implementation. There is no `Task.Run(Action<T>)` like method to call. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer when it's wrong. It's not at all equivalent of passing state object.

Comment: @Zer0 a state object is the second paremeter in Task.Factory.StartNew https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321456(v=vs.110).aspx and it saves the value of the object at the moment of the call to StartNew, while your answer creates a closure, which keeps the reference (if the value of param changes before the task is run it will also change in the task), so your code is not at all equivalent to what the question was asking. The answer really is that there is no way to write it with Task.Run().

Comment: @EgorPavlikhin - What?  `Task.Run` is short-hand for `Task.Factory.StartNew`.  They are quite literally [one in the same](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).  I want this crystal clear so no one gets misinformation from your comment.  Modifying an object you pass to `Task.Factory.StartNew` is **not** thread-safe.  It does _not_ create a copy.  It's just as dangerous as using a closure.  You're far beyond the scope of OP's question. Yet again, I answered his simple bolded question correctly.  This isn't an in depth class on closures.  EOD.

Comment: @EgorPavlikhin -  For you, and others, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550777/about-the-task-startnewactionobject-object-method) for a better discussion of that particular overload.  Totally off-topic but it's more in depth.  Outside the scope of this question and a better place to look.  Closures are something I'm not going into here.  But you can get tripped up by them regardless if you're using `StartNew` or `Task.Run` as they do the same thing, one is simply short-hand.

Comment: @Zer0 for structs Task.Run with closure and Task.Factory.StartNew with 2nd parameter (which is not the same as Task.Run per your link) *will* behave differently, since in the latter case a copy will be made. My mistake was in referring to objects in general in the original comment, what I meant was that they are not fully equivalent.

Comment: @EgorPavlikhin Still incorrect. `Task.Run` IS absolutely implemented the same way. Did you not read the link I included? Perhaps you should read the actual source code? You are discussing closures, period. Common language feature has no ties with the TPL in any way. Again... closures are a big part of C# and not at all something unique to `Task.Run`. You can use the synonymous short hand method _without_ closures too... Lastly closures are dangerous for _both_ reference types and structs. So you're off there as well. End of discussion.

Comment: @Zer0 Perhaps *you* should read the source code. One passes the state object, the other one doesn't. Which is what I said from the begining. Task.Run is **not** a short-hand for Task.Factory.StartNew. The state object version is there for legacy reasons, but it is still there and it behaves differently sometimes, so people should be aware of that.

Comment: OMG.  That's the TL'DR-est explanation of a simple question I've seen yet, and that's usually an indication of not getting the concept therefore not being able to articulate it simply. That said, the example is no good, so explaining why it's no good (not thread safe) is less desirable than just providing a working example or maybe deleting the answer.

Comment: @Zer0 if am doing this, it works fine
Task.Run(() => Myfunc(Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4));

but i want to pass the token and taskcreationoptions, so if i do as below i get many errors
Task.Run(() => Myfunc(Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4),mycancellationtoken,TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

Comment: @Harry Task.Run does not support specifying your own task creation options. It defaults to DenyChildAttach (not None). Use Task.Factory.StartNew instead.

Comment: Reading Toub's article I will highlight this sentence " You get to use overloads that accept object state, which for performance-sensitive code paths can be used to avoid closures and the corresponding allocations". I think this is what @Zero is implying when considering Task.Run over StartNew usage.

Comment: In case anyone else wants to see the difference that @Zer0 pointed out - try `for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) { Task.Run(() => Console.Out.WriteLine(i)); }` vs `for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) { Task.Factory.StartNew((j) => Console.Out.WriteLine(j), i); }`

Answer (score 41):

Use variable capture to "pass in" parameters.

```
var x = rawData;
Task.Run(() =>
{
    // Do something with 'x'
});
```

You also could use `rawData` directly but you must be careful, if you change the value of `rawData` outside of a task (for example a iterator in a `for` loop) it will also change the value inside of the task.

Comment: +1 for taking into consideration the important fact that the variable might be changed right after calling `Task.Run`.

Comment: how is this going to help?
if you use x inside the task thread, and x is a reference to an object, and if the object is modified in the same time when the task thread is running it can lead to havoc.

Comment: @Ovi-WanKenobi Yes, but that is not what this question was about. It was how to pass a parameter. If you passed a reference to a object as a parameter to a normal function you would have the exact same problem there too.

Comment: Yup this does not work. My task has no reference back to x in the calling thread. I just get null.

Comment: Scott Chamberlain,

Passing argument via capture comes with its own issues.  In particular, there is the issue of memory leaking and memory pressure.  In particular when you try to scale up.  (see "8 Ways You can Cause Memory Leaks" for more details).

Answer (score 16):

From now you can also :

```
Action<int> action = (o) => Thread.Sleep(o);
int param = 10;
await new TaskFactory().StartNew(action, param)
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it allows a state to be passed in, and prevents the possible situation mentioned in [Kaden Burgart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40029969/197591). For example, if you need to pass a `IDisposable` object into the task delegate to resolve the ReSharper warning _"Captured variable is disposed in the outer scope"_, this does it very nicely. Contrary to popular belief, there's nothing wrong with using `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead of `Task.Run` where you need to pass state. See [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

Comment: While this is good a point direction what to do, but the example above  will not compile. `StartNew` need `Action<object>` as parameter...

Comment: @Kirsan I got this to compile by changing the signature of Action<int> to Action<object?> in .Net 6.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old thread, but I wanted to share a solution I ended up having to use since the accepted post still has an issue.

The Issue:

As pointed out by Alexandre Severino, if `param` (in the function below) changes shortly after the function call, you might get some unexpected behavior in `MethodWithParameter`.

```
Task.Run(() => MethodWithParameter(param));
```

My Solution:

To account for this, I ended up writing something more like the following line of code:

```
(new Func<T, Task>(async (p) => await Task.Run(() => MethodWithParam(p)))).Invoke(param);
```

This allowed me to safely use the parameter asynchronously despite the fact that the parameter changed very quickly after starting the task (which caused issues with the posted solution).

Using this approach, `param` (value type) gets its value passed in, so even if the async method runs after `param` changes, `p` will have whatever value `param` had when this line of code ran.

Comment: I eagerly await anyone who can think of a way to do this more legibly with less overhead. This is admittedly rather ugly.

Comment: Here you go: `var localParam = param; await Task.Run(() => MethodWithParam(localParam));`

Comment: Which, by the way, Stephen already discussed in his answer, a year and a half ago.

Comment: @Servy: That was [Scott's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30225556/263693), actually. I didn't answer this one.

Comment: Scott's answer would not have worked for me actually, as I was running this in a for loop. The local param would have been reset in the next iteration.
The difference in the answer I posted is that the param gets copied into the scope of the lambda expression, so the variable is immediately safe. In Scott's answer, the parameter is still in the same scope, so it could still change between calling the line, and executing the async function.

Answer (score 4):

Just use Task.Run

```
var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    //this will already share scope with rawData, no need to use a placeholder
});
```

Or, if you would like to use it in a method and await the task later

```
public Task<T> SomethingAsync<T>()
{
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //presumably do something which takes a few ms here
        //this will share scope with any passed parameters in the method
        return default(T);
    });

    return task;
}
```

Comment: Just be careful of closures if you do it that way `for(int rawData = 0; rawData < 10; ++rawData) { Task.Run(() => { Console.WriteLine(rawData); } ) }` will not behave the same as if `rawData` was passed in like in the OP's StartNew example.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - That seems like a different example ;) I would hope most people understand about closing over lambda values.

Comment: And if those previous comments made no sense, please see Eric Lipper's blog on the topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx It explains why this happens very well.

Answer (score 4):

It's unclear if the original problem was the same problem I had: wanting to max CPU threads on computation inside a loop while preserving the iterator's value and keeping inline to avoid passing a ton of variables to a worker function.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
{
    Task.Run(() => {
        var x = ComputeStuff(datavector, i); // value of i was incorrect
        var y = ComputeMoreStuff(x);
        // ...
    });
}
```

I got this to work by changing the outer iterator and localizing its value with a gate.

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < 300; ii++)
{
    System.Threading.CountdownEvent handoff = new System.Threading.CountdownEvent(1);
    Task.Run(() => {
        int i = ii;
        handoff.Signal();

        var x = ComputeStuff(datavector, i);
        var y = ComputeMoreStuff(x);
        // ...

    });
    handoff.Wait();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Idea is to avoid using a Signal like above.
Pumping int values into a struct prevents those values from changing (in the struct).
I had the following Problem: loop var i would change before DoSomething(i) was called (i was incremented at end of loop before ()=> DoSomething(i,i*i) was called). With the structs it doesn't happen anymore. Nasty bug to find: DoSomething(i, i*i) looks great, but never sure if it gets called each time with a different value for i (or just a 100 times with i=100), hence -> struct

```
struct Job { public int P1; public int P2; }
…
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var job = new Job { P1 = i, P2 = i * i}; // structs immutable...
    Task.Run(() => DoSomething(job));
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it was flagged for review.  Answers with no explanation are often considered low-quality. Please provide some commentary for why this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of doing this. I found it useful.

```
int param;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(someMethod, param);
void someMethod(object parameter){
    var param = (int) parameter;
    // do the job
}
```