# C# Delegate Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

Please consider the following:

```
private static string Sub(int anInt)
{
    return anInt.ToString();
}

private static void Test()
{
    const int anInt = 100;

    Func<int,string> aFunc = Sub;

    //why does Task<string> task = Task.Run(aFunc(anInt)); not compile?
    Task<string> task = Task.Run(() => aFunc(anInt));

    Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
}
```

This code compiles fine. Why does the line

```
Task<string> task = Task.Run(aFunc(anInt));
```

not compile?

Is there a way to pass in a delegate invocation without a Lambda expression?

What am I missing?

Comment: The error that you're getting is telling you *exactly* why it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

The error states

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Action'

By passing `aFunc(anInt)` you're basically passing the result of the method invocation - a string. Think of it this way - if you're typing `()` after the name of the Func variable - you're executing it on the spot.

If you want to pass a Func with its parameters, you have to do it the exact same way you said it compiles for you:

```
Task<string> task = Task.Run(() => aFunc(anInt));
```

... because this wraps your invocation in a new executable, which is then run.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225476/task-run-with-parameters) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse this line:

```cs
Task<string> task = Task.Run(aFunc(anInt));
```

This line does not compile because the compiler understands `aFunc(anInt)` as "*Execute `aFunc(anInt)`, then use its return value as the parameter when calling `Task.Run()`*".

Essentially, you are trying to force a string into `Task.Run`. It is equivalent to trying this:

```cs
Task<string> task = Task.Run("blah");
```

The above line will produce the exact same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because you are invoking `aFunc` instead of referring to it.

If you start passing parameters to a method, instead of simply giving its name, you're invoking it.

To refer to a method, only give the name and do not pass any parameters. Just like what you did here:

```
Func<int,string> aFunc = Sub;
```

You don't pass any parameters to `Sub` because you're just saying "What I mean is *that* method called `Sub`".

Now let's look at the erroneous code:

```
Task<string> task = Task.Run(aFunc(anInt));
```

`Task.Run` takes a parameter of type `Action` but you're giving it the return value of `aFunc`, which is a string. See why it's producing the error now?

You just can't say "What I mean is this method, called with an argument of `anInt`". It's simply impossible. You have to create a lambda for this.