# Task.Run with Input Parameters and Output

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

This works great:

```
private void MainMethod()
{
    Task<bool> taskItemFound = new Task<bool>(ItemFound);
}

private bool ItemFound()
{
    //Do Work
    return true;
}
```

This works but is UGLY and I can't pass more than one parameter:

```
private void MainMethod()
{
    var startNew = Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(TempMethod, "cow");
}

private bool TempMethod(object o)
{
    return ("holy " + o == "holy cow");
}
```

I'm looking for a solution that will give me a `Task<bool>` from an existing method with more than one input parameter and that returns a bool. Ideally, it would look like this:

```
Task<bool> taskItemFound = new Task<bool>(ItemFound(param1, param2, param3));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
bool result = await Task.Run(() => ItemFound(param1, param2, param3) );
```

Or if you really want it as `Task<bool>`:

```
Task<bool> t = new Task<bool>(() => ItemFound(param1, param2, param3) );
```

Comment: Yes, but worth noticing that param1, param2 etc are now captured (closed over). They are treated very differently from the original `object o`

Comment: Can that cause any side effects? How are they treated differently?

Comment: Yes, they are shared and their scope and lifetime are hard to control or even gauge.

Comment: But I'm also curious now... @GregaMohorko How are they different, and what side effects might i look out for?

Comment: I don't know, ask @HenkHolterman, I have been using Task.Run like this for 4+ years now, and I never noticed anything about objects being treated differently.

Comment: @GregorMohorko Their values can change by the time they are used in the lambda function. Not ideal...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, a more clear way would be passing the parameters inside an object.
Below you can find solutions to easily achieve that.

#### Solution 1 (long but clear): Pass an object which holds the parameters

Just create a class which holds the parameters:

```
class CustomParams
{
   public int Param1 { get; set; }
   public int Param2 { get; set; }
   public int Param3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the method just to cast the object to the class

```
private bool TempMethod(object arguments)
{
    var args = arguments as CustomParams;
    // Do anything with args.Param1
    // Do anything with args.Param2
    // Do anything with args.Param3
    // Return anything
    return ("holy " + args.Param1 == "holy cow");
}
```

And to call, use this:

```
Task<bool> taskItemFound = new Task<bool>(TempMethod, new CustomParams {
    Param1 = 3,
    Param2 = 5,
    Param3 = 2
});
```

#### Solution 2 (hacky but shorter): Use Tuples as parameters

This can be used **in case** you don't want to create a class

Modify the method to cast the object to tuple:

```
private bool TempMethod(object arguments)
{
    var args = arguments as Tuple<int,int,int>;
    // Do anything with args.Item1
    // Do anything with args.Item2
    // Do anything with args.Item3
    // Return anything
    return ("holy " + args.Item1 == "holy cow");
}
```

Then use:

```
Task<bool> taskItemFound = new Task<bool>(ItemFound, new Tuple<int, int>(3,5,7));
```

#### Solution 3 (super-hacky, and short): Use dynamic objects

Modify the method to accept `dynamic` instead of object:

```
private bool TempMethod(dynamic arguments)
{
    // Do anything with args.Param1
    // Do anything with args.Param2
    // Do anything with args.Param3
    // Return anything
    return ("holy " + arguments.Param1 == "holy cow");
}
```

And then call using this:

```
Task<bool> taskItemFound = new Task<bool>(TempMethod, new {Param1 = 3, Param2 = 44, Param3 = 564 });
```